# Access denied in Window10 running powershell as administrator

Tags: powershell, window

I run the cmd prompt as administrator.
The cmd is  `attrib +h +s +r filename.png`
.But the error `Access denied` is appeared.Can someone help me to get through .I already searching in google .Nothing have solved it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your permissions to the file, remove TrustedInstaller and add yourself make sure you check everything on, then try again.